# How to define a "line" and "symmetry w.r.t. a line" in $L_2(\lambda)$ space

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, convex-analysis, lebesgue-integral

For any $x,y\in L_2([0,1],\lambda)$, define the inner product $\langle. , . \rangle$ by

\begin{equation}
\langle x, y \rangle=\int_{[0,1]}  x(t) y(t) \lambda (dt) 
\end{equation}

Is it proper to define a line and the symmetry w.r.t a line as follows?

Definition: For any $x,y\in L_2 ([0,1],\lambda)$, a line $l(x, y)$  is the set of all points of the form  $x+k y$ for some  $k\in R$.

A set $W\subset L_2([0,1],\lambda) $ is symmetric with respect to $l( x, y )$ if for every $z\in L_2([0,1],\lambda)$ satisfying $\langle z, y \rangle=0$, we have $x+ky+z\in W$ implies $x+ky-z\in W$.

Comment: That is one way of expressing the concept of symmetry with respect to a line. Note that this is simply analytic geometry. Integrals and Lebesgue spaces are nothing more than window dressing specifying the particular vector space you want to apply the definition to. They have nothing to do with the definition itself. And I see no reason at all for the functional-analysis and convex-analysis tags.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that looks correct. And you can write down the reflection operator $R$ and then define $W$ to be symmetric about the line if $RW=W$. Using orthogonal projection, you can write $w$ as
$$
\begin{align}
          w & = w-\left((w-x)-\frac{\langle w-x,y\rangle}{\langle y,y\rangle}y\right)+\left((w-x)-\frac{\langle w-x,y\rangle}{\langle y,y\rangle}y\right) \\
            & = x+\frac{\langle w-x,y\rangle}{\langle y,y,\rangle}y+\left((w-x)-\frac{\langle w-x,y\rangle}{\langle y,y\rangle}y\right)
\end{align}
$$
The final expression is a point on the line + a vector that is orthogonal to the direction vector $y$. Therefore, the reflection operator is
$$
           Rw =  x+\frac{\langle w-x,y\rangle}{\langle y,y\rangle}y-\left((w-x)-\frac{\langle w-x,y\rangle}{\langle y,y\rangle}y\right) \\
          = 2x-w+2\frac{\langle w-x,y\rangle}{\langle y,y\rangle}y
$$

Comment: Hi, thanks. Is it the definition special to Hilbert space?

Comment: @user91360 : The above works for an inner product space ; completeness of the space is not required. Normed space without an inner product doesn't give you a unique way to reflect.

Comment: so reflection w.r.t a line is different to w.r.t.  a halfspace?  It seems that two reflection operators are similar?

Comment: sorry，a halfspace I mean a hyperplane.  Would one notion of symmetry imply another?

Comment: For $\mathbb{R}^{3}$: Reflection across a 2d plane is very different than reflection through a line.